# Data recurring in previous 90 days

Tags: sql, oracle

I hope you can suppor me with  a piece of code I'm writing. I'm working with the following query:

```
SELECT case_id, case_date, people_id FROM table_1;
```

and I've to search in the DB how many times the same people_id is repeted in the DB, (different case_id) considering the case_date -90days timeframe. Any advise on how to address that?

Data sample

[image]

Additional info: as results I'm expecting to have the list of people_id with how many cases received in the 90 days from the last case_date.

expected result sample:

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear if you want just one row.  Or a count for the preceding 90 days for each row.  Or if the count is unique people.  Or if the count is the rows.  Or perhaps something else entirely.

Comment: @GordonLinoff additional info added, hopefully it is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the question, it would be something like this:

```
select people_id,
       case_id,
       count(*)
from table_1
where case_date >= trunc(sysdate) - 90
group by people_id,
         case_id
```

Comment: Or possibly they meant `count(distinct case_id)`...

Comment: Maybe, @trincot, can't tell. As I said, that's how **I** understood it. Sample data would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter `WHERE` the `case_date` is greater than or equal to 90 days before the start of today and then `GROUP BY` the `people_id` and `COUNT` the number of `DISTINCT` (different) `case_id`:

```sql
SELECT people_id,
       COUNT( DISTINCT case_id ) AS number_of_cases
FROM   table_1
WHERE  case_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '90' DAY
GROUP BY
       people_id;
```

If you only want to count repeated `case_id` per `person_id` then:

```sql
SELECT person_id,
       COUNT(*) AS number_of_repeated_cases
FROM   (
  SELECT case_id,
         person_id,
  FROM   table_1
  WHERE  case_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '90' DAY
  GROUP BY
         people_id,
         case_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
)
GROUP BY
       people_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want window functions:

```
select t.*,
       count(*) over (partition by people_idorder by case_date
                      range between interval '90' day preceding and current row
                     ) as person_count_90_day
from t;
```